# Spring Profiles in combination with ConfigServer

Tags: properties, spring-profiles, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a very basic Spring Boot Config Server (just added the dependency and annotated mainclass with @EnableConfigServer).

In general I would like to support multiple environments with different propertysources for each of my applications, here is the example of the ConfigServer itself:

Profile: default (application.yml on classpath):

[image]

Profile: docker (application-docker.yml on classpath):

[image]

Profile: default (application.yml in repository of ConfigServer):

[image]

So in my case all of the properties from all of the three screenshots should be active, I'd expect the order/priority as follows:

1. application.yml from classpath
2. application-*ANY_PROFILE*.yml from classpath
3. application.yml from config repo
4. *APP-NAME*.yml from config repo (does not exists in this case)

So far this works flawlessly, except the issue that I'm having is that my application-docker.yml on classpath is beeing ignored when I start the application with the command (of course inside the container):

```
java -jar -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=docker *.jar
```

as you can see here:
[image]

My question is, even when I provide the profile as command line argument its not beeing picked up.
Why is that?

**UPDATE**, here is the Dockerfile and entrpoint.sh:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To activate one or more profiles do one of the following:

1. Activate using the VM parameters `-Dspring.profiles.active=<profiles>`
2. Activate using program arguments `--spring.profiles.active=<profiles>`

Following your example, the following should work:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=docker *.jar
```